# Models with incremental number using a for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop, gtsummary

**I want to run a model function that I have created through multiple variables in my dataframe and produce various models with incremental numbers.**

Data Setup

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survey)
library(gtsummary)
library(srvyr)

#Loading data
data(API)

#Declaring Survey design 
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)

#Create a model that takes in a string variable, runs a regression model, and stores the result in a gtsummary table. 
mod_create <- function(y){
  model <- svyglm(reformulate(paste0(y, "both")), 
                          design = dclus1, 
                          family = quasibinomial())
  tbl <- tbl_regression(model, 
                    exponentiate = TRUE) %>% add_global_p()
  return(tbl)
}
```

I want to run this function, to run the model detailed above and store the result in a gtsummary table for multiple variables in the dataframe.

For example; I want to assess the relationship between having "both" parents and its effect on multiple variables (api00, api99, target, and growth). Location within dataframe --> apiclus1[12:15]

I tried this:

```
#For loop
vars_to_mod <- colnames(apiclus1[12:15])

List <- list()
for (i in 1:length(vars_to_mod))
{
  List[[i]] <- mod_create(vars_to_mod[i])
} 

#List of your models
names(List) <- paste0('table.',1:length(vars_to_mod))
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in svyglm.survey.design(reformulate(paste0(y, "both")), design = dclus1, : 
all variables must be in design= argument
```

Comment: What is the value of `y` when this fails? Are you able to reformulate this outside of the function and `for` loop?

Comment: Try creating the formula before passing it to `svyglm()`. `formula <- stringr::str_glue("{y} ~ both") |> as.formula()`. Then pass the constructed formula to the modeling function.